# Dynamic Form with Dependent drop down

Tags: php, mysql, forms, yii2

Hey Developers i'm building a application form where the user input data into the different fields. One part of the application is a dynamic form from https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform. Now inside the dynamic form i have a dependent drop down but when i click the [+] sign the dependent drop down change data on the first row and not the second.

Here's my code.

in my controller

```
 public function actionLists($name)
    {
         $countHs= Hs::find()
                        ->where(['hscode'=> $name])
                        ->count();
         $Hs  = Hs::find()
                 ->where(['hscode'=> $name])
                 ->all();
         if($countHs > 0)
         { 
             foreach ($Hs as $H)
             {
                 echo "<option value='".$H->hsproduct."'> ".$H->hsproduct."</option>";


             }
         }else{
                 echo "<option> - </option>";
             }


    }
```

and my form

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 135px">
     <?= $form->field($modelsItems, "[{$i}]hscode")->dropDownList(
                                    ArrayHelper::map(Hs::find()->all(),'hscode','hsproduct'),                      

                                        [


                                            'prompt'=>'',

                                         'onchange'=>

                                        '$.get( "'.Url::toRoute('/hs/lists').'", { name: $(this).val() })
         .done(function( data ) { $( "#'.Html::getInputId($modelsItems, "[{$i}]hsproduct").'" ).html( data ); } );'

                                            ])->label('HS.Code'); 


                                ?>  

        </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 135px">
   <?= $form->field($modelsItems, "[{$i}]hsproduct")->dropDownList(
                                    ArrayHelper::map(Hs::find()->all(),'hsproduct','hsproduct'),
                                    [
                                     'prompt'=>'',
                                    ])->label('HS.Product');
                                 ?>  
        </div>
```

Im a newbie sorry for my english

Comment: Perhaps can you show a screenshot of how it looks like? Maybe it would be a little easier to understand. Not sure if I can answer this, though.

Comment: This is the link to the screen shots. http://imgur.com/a/nCISa

Comment: How is the first row working? With your JavaScript? I actually can write a JavaScript function/event that can help you to get values to specific field.

Comment: i use an on change event in my form. 'onchange'=>

                                        '$.get( "'.Url::toRoute('/hs/lists').'", { name: $(this).val() })
         .done(function( data ) { $( "#'.Html::getInputId($modelsItems, "[{$i}]hsproduct").'" ).html( data ); } );'

                                            ])

Comment: ($modelsItems, "[{$i}]hsproduct") the [{$i}] is the counter for the dynamic form and it seems when a new row is created the counter increases by one but in the onchange it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated for your case.

What I did was I declared global variable in JS file `var i` and assigned `0`. After the first event is fired, I increase variable `i` by one. Now it contains 1 in memory. Next time it will take 1 and add 1 again. And so on:

```
var i = 0;

$(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {
    i++;
})
```

Note that this will only work if you choose in each row just once and you will not come back to specific row. If you want to do something like that, you should instead get element ID's number, parse to float (instead of string) and use that number to your event script.

```
parseFloat($('#hs-0-hscode')[0].id.split('-')[1])
```

*Leaving below one additional solution (but not according to yours). Just in case.*

---

Use `Inspect source` and find how your input fields are named (name or ID). Let's say, we have `name="hs-0-hscode"`. This is for just Then your jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {
    if ($(this)[0].id.indexOf('hscode') > 0) {
        // Now you can use Ajax to get a list of items you want to show.
        // Element itself can be reached: $(this).parent().parent().parent().children().eq(1);
        // For example:
        // var data = $.parseJSON(results);
        // $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        //    $('#client-company_size')
        //        .append($("<option></option>")
        //        .attr("value", key)
        //        .text(value)); 
        // });
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry for the delay, the problem is that the hs-0-hsproduct is incremented every time by one.so the id for the next row will be hs-1-hsproduct and if the user want to edit the hs-0-hsproduct it doesn't allow it

Comment: @user5469526 That's true, that's why I suggested to use that one with `parseFloat`.

Comment: i have multiple of drop down but when the user select the hs code the information that is linked with it will be displayed in the next dropdown. its it recommended to use the drop down or a textinput?just a concern.

Comment: can you give me a little more idea on the how to get the id to parsefloat. not too familiar with it

Comment: @user5469526 Use that last code block I gave to you (with a lot of comments) but instead of comments (after `if`) write something like: `i = parseFloat($(this)[0].id.split('-')[1]);` After this try to add your JavaScript code.

Comment: It works.. Thanks a lot Edvin Tenovimas. Thanks for your patience mien.

Comment: @user5469526 I'm glad you were able to solve that. :)